# Changing Page Layouts in Production using Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, visualforce, page-layout

I am trying to simplify the fields for the `account`, `contact`, and `opportunities` page layouts in my company's salesforce account.  To do this I have begun by creating a new page layout in the developer Sandbox each for `account`, `contact`, and `opportunities` with new fields added and others removed from the current layout being used.

Once I am finished completely recreating the page layouts how do I change the layout in production to my new layout set up in Sandbox including new fields etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You would have to deploy them to the production environment. One such tool for doing this is [change sets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm&language=en).

When you are doing a deployment, you should pay attention to the name of the layout that you are deploying. If it has the same name as the layout in production, the layout in production will be overwritten. If it has a different name, both layouts will be present in production after the deployment and you will be able to manually assign the layouts.

Comment: Thanks that helps!  So if I gave it a different name than he current layout in production is there a way to select my new layout as the default for production and change all records to the new layout at one time?

Comment: @Dataman434 The `Page Layout` that a user sees is determined by the `Record Type` of the record being viewed and the user's `Profile`. If you go to **Setup** > **Customize** > **Account** > **Page Layout**, and click on the button that says **Page Layout Assignment**, you will see a grid that allows you to manage layouts. Here you can make that change so that all users see all records with the new layout if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use salesforce deployment `change set` or deployment tools for this like `Ant Migration Tool`, `Force.com IDE`, `Mavens Mate` etc to migrate the  updated page layout from sandbox to production.

I hope these below links will help you :

[Deploying Components to Production](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_deploy.htm)
[Deploying a Change Set](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_inbound_deploy.htm&language=en_US)